# Julia type questions

Tags: types, integer, julia

**1** Why is it that when I define a variable and its type inside of a function everything's fine, but when it's a global variable I get error?
Example:

```
  n::Int8 = 3
  ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: n not defined
```

**2** Why is it that when I do some simple operations the variable type changes? Examples:

```
julia> function main()
           n::Int8 = 5
           c = collect(1:n)
           println(c)
           println(typeof(c))
       end
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
[1,2,3,4,5]
Array{Int64,1}


julia> n = zero(Int8)
0
julia> typeof(ans)
Int8
julia> n += 5
5
julia> typeof(ans)
Int64
```

**3** How to maintain the variable initial type?

Comment: In `n += 5`, which is `n = n + 5`, `5` is an Int64. Try `n += Int8(5)`. Otherwise, when adding an Int64 to an Int8, getting an Int64 is reasonable (look for 'promotion' in the Julia book).

Comment: Similarily, try `collect(Int8(1):Int8(5))`.

Comment: isn't the assertion `n::Int8` redundant when it is later assigned a value (`= 3`)? Also, I think `Int` is automatically converted to the appropriate type based on the hardware Julia is running on, that's why `collect(1:n)` results in an `Int64` Array. see http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#integers

Comment: You can also use the [`one`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/numbers/?highlight=one#Base.one) function in this case: `c = collect(one(n):n)::Vector{Int8}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Julia 0.4), questions 1 & 2 are answered by [this statement](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#type-declarations) in the Julia manual:

> Currently, type declarations cannot be used in global scope, e.g. in the REPL, since Julia does not yet have constant-type globals.

As discussed in the comments, there are several options for #3.